# Shopping cart like rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new rails developer building a site that is a delivery service for dry cleaning.

The user is going to select how many items they want picked up, pants, shirts ect.

Here is my table:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.decimal  "price"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "product_type"
  t.text     "image"
end
```

All of the products are saved in the database. I want each user to be able to select the quantity and type of clothing and quantity on the order page.

How would I go about adding order total and add the transaction to their recent order history of all the items selected?

I believe I will need jquery to update the database selected at all times once the item is checked. Add selected items to an order database if selected and sum up order total for payment?

Sorry, noob question, thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a super-broad question. Basically, it amounts to "how do I write this app"? Do you think it's answerable with a short stackoverflow post?

Comment: No, I am not asking for how do write this app. I am asking for the best approach of calculating order total of selected items. Theres is very little documentation on the web, so I feel like this will benefit lots of ruby developers.

Comment: Hm, to get the order total, you get order's line items and sum them. Simple as that. That's the "calculating" part. But then you also have that other question: "how do I add the transaction to user's recent order history", which implies that you don't yet fully imagine how to build an order history, etc. Of course, there's not much documentation on your not-yet-existing app. What you need are courses/books/knowledge on general app design/architecture. All this is, again, far too broad for this site.

Comment: I have another database set with basic user information, address, ect with a My Account page. Which displays all information for that specific user. Each user has an order history column, just blank at the moment.

Comment: Order history column? No-no, this will never work. It should be a separate table, `orders`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually built an e-commerce relatively recently, so here's what I did.
I created separate models called `Cart` and `CartItem`. You can just switch the model `Phone` to `Product` (or whatever the model used to store information related to the product (i.e.: price, quantity available, etc.)

```
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart, {:optional => true}
  belongs_to :phone, {:optional => true}
end

class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
  has_many :cart_items
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_items
end
```

The `Cart` model has no attributes. Its main purpose is just to hold different cart items.

The  `CartItem` model has a foreign key of which cart it belongs to (`cart_id`) as well as a foreign key on which phone it has (`phone_id`) (you can switch it to clothing). Each cart item can only have one phone, and a corresponding quantity for that phone . Thus you can cycle through `@user.cart.cart_items` and get each clothing item as well as the quantity associated with each clothing.

Attributes required for the model `CartItem`:

```
t.integer  "cart_id"
t.integer  "phone_id"
t.integer  "quantity_sold"
```

Thus using these models, and their respective attributes, you can calculate totals by having a `calculate_total` method that gets run everytime you go to the cart page:

```
def calculate_totals
  phones_array = []
  if @user.cart.cart_items.present?
    @user.cart.cart_items.each do |item|
      phone_total = item.phone.price * item.quantity_sold
      phones_array << phone_total
    end
    @subtotal = phones_array.inject{|memo,n| memo + n}
    @tax_total = @subtotal * 0.13
    @total = @subtotal + @tax_total
  end
end

def cart
  calculate_totals
end
```

Note it will only run if `@user` has cart items . As you can see for the controller method `calculate_totals`, you basically iterate through your cart items, grab the price of each of the items and multiply it by the quantity sold. The result then gets stored in the `phones_array` variable.

To calculate `@subtotal`, you're simply adding all the elements of `phones_array` with `.inject`. You get `@tax_total` by multiplying `@subtotal` by the tax rate and to calculate `@total` you're just adding `@subtotal` by `@tax_total`.